# search in SAP software using SAPRFC

Tags: php, search, saprfc

I am using http://saprfc.sourceforge.net/ to connect to SAP software and get results.

The below code searches for only one customer.

Is there a way to make a search for a couple of customers using only http://saprfc.sourceforge.net/ and without creating a new connection?

```
$fce = saprfc_function_discover($rfc,"ZBAPI_CUSTOMER");
$customerSAP="0000000000539";
$customerSAP=substr($customerSAP,-10);
$IMPORTT = array ("ZCUSTOMER" => $customerSAP );
saprfc_import ($fce,"CUSTOMERNO",$customerSAP);
saprfc_table_init ($fce,"ZBAPICUSTOMER");
saprfc_exception()
$rfc_rc = saprfc_call_and_receive ($fce);
saprfc_function_debug_info($fce);
saprfc_function_free($fce);
saprfc_close($rfc);
```

Comment: What have you tried to do so? And - do you want to select multiple customers or just issue the call to your custom "BAPI" a number of times?

Comment: what i tried to do is this. when i trie to look for other customer i need to do this again. so if i want to get info for a lot of customers i need to do this a lot of times. my question is this: is there a way to get this info for a lot of users doing this one time. like in mysql
where i use for example id in ('1','2','3') and etc

Comment: man-qa 10x for edit. my english is not good as you can see :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a question of the library you use to make the call, but rather of the function module you call. From the name `ZBAPI_CUSTOMER` I can see that it's a custom module, and that is about it. What it can do - that is, whether it can retrieve multiple customers - cannot be deduced from this. Contact your SAP department, they will most certainly be able to tell you more about this.

Answer (score 0):

The logic of the BAPI may not support providing more than one customer record as an input. It looks like this custom BAPI may require a structure of data for the read action. If however the input type is a table then you could provide more than one record in the call.
You would need to understand what the characterictics are of this custom BAPI
the Z prefix indicates it is custom.